# How to detect app is exiting?

Tags: android, actionscript-3, air

While my app is in the background, Android exits the app when there is not enough RAM or for other reasons. Most of the time not actually exiting, I mean the app remains open but does not run in the background and when you go back to the app it starts over. (Just like many other apps.)

How to detect app is exiting?

- I already use NativeApplication.nativeApplication.executeInBackground for other tasks but this is different.
- I already use Event.DEACTIVATE for other tasks but this is also different.
- Event.EXITING does not work.
- Event.CLOSING does not work.
- Event.SUSPEND does not work.

I just want to know the application is exiting and perform some tasks before it exits.

Answer (score 0):

You can't accurately detect an app is exiting, as many of the causes of it exiting are uncatchable (for example. a crash.  The device running out of battery.  The user hard rebooting, etc).  Do not write code assuming you can catch this event-  either have the code run on the next start, or run it before the app exits (for example, on a timer, or when the app goes into the background).

Comment: Well I also cannot catch any event when I deliberately exit the app. I triggers nothing no Event.EXITING or any other event. Can we say these kind of events do not work on Android platform at all?

Comment: @Serdar I have no idea how they're implemented in air to say if they work or not.  But I would say that as a general rule of computer science, assuming you can detect the end of a running application from within that application is a bad idea.

Comment: Agreed, I guessed, as these events are part of the framework, it is at least usable when the app is not crashing but exiting gracefully.